# jQuery's live functionality without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how to achieve jQuery's .live functionality with "traditional" JavaScript. I want something like $('a').live('mouseover', mouseover_func) to be written as usual JavaScript. But how?

Answer (score 10):

Bind a "mouseover" event handler to the `<body>` element.  In that handler, check the "target" property of each event it catches and see whether its "tagName" property is "A".  If so, call the handler.

The "live" feature leverages event "bubbling", which is the name for the browsers process of checking for handlers from the target element to the root of the DOM, one parent at a time. Since each `<a>` in your document can ultimately be traced back up to the `<body>`, that root node will get all the "mouseover" events that aren't shunted off by lower-level handlers that cancel bubbling (via the "stopPropagation()" method on the event object, or some weird browser-specific way I guess).

Not all events bubble, however. I'm looking around for a good reference ... ok here, the [MDC page seems pretty good](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM_Client_Object_Cross-Reference/DOM_Events) though a little old maybe.

Comment: I though 'live' was to automatically bind the event to new elements that match the same selector. Is this achieved through bubbling? I wouldn't think so.

Comment: I think the answer sounds right. If you mouseover a newly formed element, it will bubble up and mouseover body. If body has a handler to check what the target is, then this would work.

Comment: @GolezTrol: bubbling is actually the only possible way to achieve it.

Comment: @Golez no, that's not really what it does.  It solves the problem you describe - handling events on dynamically-added elements - by using the bubbling trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the  jQuery source code to see how it does it. That's one of the joys of open source. You will learn an awful lot...